# Dynamically injecting values in $stateProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have route which has a `permission` object having an `array` of access

```
angular.module('app')
    .config(['$stateProvider',function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('staffpanel', {
          url: '...',
          data: {
            permissions: {
              access: ['admin', 'moderator']
            }
          }
     });
}])
```

From my service i am getting an array which has dynamic values like this:

```
var access = ['admin', 'business','moderator];
```

Is there a way i can inject this `array` in my `permission` object? In the config i can use only `provider` and `constant`. Is there anyway we can dynamically inject the values for `access` array when the `config` function runs?

Comment: can create your own provider. Not 100% clear what you are trying to do though ... or what the actual source is for the `access` array in your service

Comment: @charlietfl: if i create a provider, it can be configured... and used in other controllers... what i want is the access array to be changed... which will decided which routes is accessible to whom.. the problem is array values are dynamic in nature...

Comment: `dynamic in nature` ... that's why the question about source? You haven't provided any relationship details or identified where they some from

Comment: What exactly does "dynamic" mean here? Show the desired usage of how the dynamic nature would manifest itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resolve` is an alternative to map dependencies. Use `resolve` if you want to have access to `factories` or `services` that can be injected into your states **after** `config` phase.

By using `resolve`, you still can pass data to your states and controllers, without much hassle. Note that at this point, `config` phase has already passed. Also note that `resolve` phase happens **before** the `controller` is loaded, so you can be sure that by the time `controller` is instantiated, your data has **already** been injected.

```
angular.module('app')
  .config(['$stateProvider',function($stateProvider){
   $stateProvider
    .state('staffpanel', {
      url: '...',
      resolve:{
          //note that you can inject other services/factories here.
          permissions:['access',function(access){
               //return useful stuffs based on your logic
               return ['admin','moderator']
         }]
      }
 });
}])
```

and at controller level, you will just access it like this:

```
angular.module('app')
 .controller('myCtrl',['$scope','permissions',function($scope,permissions){
    console.log(permissions); //['admin', 'moderator']
}]
```

However, for someother reasons, if you will need to do configuration settings **during** `config` phase, then you will have to use providers.

```
angular.module('app')
 //inject your other providers here!
 .config(['$stateProvider', 'accessProvider', function($stateProvider,accessProvider){
 $stateProvider
    .state('staffpanel', {
      url: '...',
      data: {
        permissions: {
          //you can use your accessProviders methods here
          access: ['admin', 'moderator']
        }
      }
 });
}])
```

It is good to know about the life cycle in AngularJs. This [doc](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Dependency-Injection) talks about the phases of dependency injection.